# How to access Tomcat 7 which runs as a service from netbeans from the Internet?

Tags: networking, tomcat7

I completed a jsp project and I would like to make it available through the Internet. I opened the port 8084 to my router and I tried to reach the URL   mypublicIP:8084, but nothing happens. I also have disabled the windows firewall and I'm not using any other firewalls. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must configure your router to forward the internet request to the particular computer that's running Tomcat. You do this by supplying the router with your computer's IP address which is different from what you're calling "mypublicIP".  In my Linksys router configuration web application it's call Port Range Forwarding.

Comment: Already done that, couldn't complete the port forwarding without that step anyway.